# JavaScript won't run even when allowed on local files

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I keep JavaScript off for sites and allow it on sites I need it on.
I could do the same to Local html files that had JS when opened with Chrome, but recently this stoped for no reason I can see.

Rundown:

(Using latest Version of google chrome)

1. I allow the local html file to use JavaScript
2. The Local file shows up in the list of allowed sites
3. Icon for disabled JS shows, says it is allowed (Icon only shows when JS is not allowed in the first place)
4. JS will not run

Any Idea how to fix this? Is this a bug with Chrome? Seems so. Please advise.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. It may have a place on http://superuser.com or somewhere on https://support.google.com/chrome/

Comment: We need more information

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Happy to move it there if its off topic. Was not sure how to categorise this and I did not know superuser existed, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a sidestep from what you're expecting - but have you considered just running a local webserver?

There are some really easy to use ones, like using python's `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`. If you are on ubuntu then this [question may be relevant](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377389/how-to-easily-start-a-webserver-in-any-folder), but some of those answers will run on Windows as well.

Comment: I use MAMP off and on. But I'd still like any info on this if its out there. I know my situation is just... well weird.